# Regex to include up to two words including the match

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture (using regex in python) up to two words preceding, but also including, my target word.

```
> Example text 1: McDonald's, King Dinuzulu Road, Durban 
> Example text 2: Queens Road, Cape Town

> desired output 1: King Dinuzulu Road
> desired output 2: Queens Road
```

I currently have `\b(?=(\w+\s+Road|Road\s+\w+)\b)`, but it only returns a single word preceding "Road"

Comment: If you have a comma-separated list why not just `split()` and then deal with a list?

Comment: Will try that, might work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
(?:\w+ ){0,2}Road\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/Qzwu6Q/1